# How to convert List<Long> to Expression<Long> int Java?

Tags: java, criteria

I have been trying for a while to convert a list of longs into a expression of longs, the purpose of the exercise is to use it in the Criteria Builder "IN" clause so it really has to be an Expression

```
List<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(1L);
numbers.add(2L);
javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<Long> expressionOfNumbers = (Expression<Long>) numbers;

//query code...
query.where(cb.in(expressionOfNumbers));
```

All help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What expression are you talking about? `com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression`?

Comment: How would you create a single `Expression<Long>`?

Comment: @Sweeper I think it would be `javax.persistence.criteria.Expression`.

Comment: Judging by the fact that author mentioned criteria api this would be org.hibernate.criterion.Expression.
Anyway, there is no simple built in way to do that. Just create a new Expression with constructor, and use a for loop to add the values. You could also use stream api and implement your own Collector. Worth considering if you do that a lot, otherwise more of a mind-training excercise

Comment: Oh yeah, it can also be what @MCEmperor said, I guess we need to wait for the author to make up his mind :D

Comment: Just clarified the question the Expression type is "javax.persistence.criteria.Expression".